# SQL: How can I find repeated value's till separation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

What I want to do with SQL is find repeating values in a column until there's an other value sorted by date.

This is my table. I use `"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"` for the date column.

```
Name    |date     
-------------------
Bart    |12-12-2014
Bart    |23-12-2014
Joost   |24-12-2014
Bart    |25-12-2014
Bart    |26-12-2014
Bart    |27-12-2014
```

So in this example I want the number "3" returned and the last known value of name, so in this case "Bart".

I hope I made myself clear, sorry for the unclear title!

Comment: I couldn't think of something to try. I had only selected the last name because that was the only thing that I needed, now I need to know how many times it occurs before a separation. So I had this code: "SELECT name, time FROM name ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 1;"

Comment: So where's the time?

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm . . . Here is one method where the logic is placed in the `where` clause:

```
select count(*), max(lastname.name)
from tablename t cross join
     (select t2.name from tablename t2 order by date desc limit 1) as lastname
where t.name = lastname.name and
      t.date > (select max(t2.date) from tablename t2 where t2.name <> lastname.name);
```

Comment: Do I need 2 table's? Or am I reading this completely wrong... I'm not so advanced with SQL so please excuse the misunderstanding:) @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Joost . . . This only uses one table, referenced twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query:

```sql
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
SELECT Name, [date],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [date]) -
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [date]) AS grp       
FROM mytable ) AS t
GROUP BY Name, grp
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

This query tries to identify islands of records, i.e. consecutive rows having the same `Name`: `grp` calculated field does exactly this.

If you want the `Name` having the largest number of consecutive records, just use `TOP 1` in the above query.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d305/1)